# Use XSLT to convert date time to full words

Tags: xml, date, xslt, time, formatting

I am just starting to learn XSLT and am hoping to convert some XML time and date data so that it is fully spelled out.  While I have seen methods to have the date information output as words (12 to December) I don't see anything that allows be to convert time (6:30 to six thirty) or the year (2005 to two thousand five).

Is there some standard way of doing this?  If not is it feasible (if lengthy) to do so using xsl:if?  I can probably limit the inputs to the quarter hours.

What about the year?

Comment: Please indicate if you're using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. -- Also post an example of input and the exact result you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0, you can use [the format-date(), format-time() and format-dateTime() functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#format-date) to format dates and time in a variety of ways, for example:

**XML**

```
<input>2014-04-30T15:45:12</input>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(input, 
            'The [DWwo] Day of [MNn] in the Year [YWw], at [hWw] Hours and [mWv] Minutes [PN]'
            )" />   
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>The Thirtieth Day of April in the Year Two Thousand and Fourteen, at Three Hours and Forty Five Minutes P.M.</output>
```

Comment: Awesome!  It is a lot easier for me to understand when looking at examples.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Someone may have written something helpful and will post a link here, but in the meanwhile a quick and dirty solution might be:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test='hour = 1'>
    one
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test='hour = 2>
    two
  </xsl:when>
  ...
</xsl:choose>
```

Date/time extraction functions are here:
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#datetime